# The first syzygy module of a binomial ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, math-software, binomial-ideals, syzygies

It is known how you compute the first syzygy module of a monomial ideal but it seems an hard work to do the same for binomial ones. I don't know any procedure to aim that, so I would like kindly if there exists something to find the first syzygy of a binomial ideal in terms of its minimal generators. For instance, I have this example in the context of determinantal rings.
Let $R$ be the polynomial ring in the twelve variables$$x_{11},x_{22},x_{12},x_{21},x_{23},x_{13},x_{24},x_{14},x_{32},x_{31},x_{42},x_{41}$$
over a field $K$. Consider the binomial ideal $I$ generated by the following 2-minors:
$$
f_1=x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21},\\
f_2=x_{11}x_{23}-x_{13}x_{21},\\
f_3=x_{11}x_{24}-x_{14}x_{21},\\
f_4=x_{11}x_{32}-x_{12}x_{31},\\
f_5=x_{11}x_{42}-x_{12}x_{41},\\
f_6=x_{21}x_{32}-x_{22}x_{31},\\
f_7=x_{21}x_{42}-x_{22}x_{41},\\
f_8=x_{31}x_{42}-x_{32}x_{41},\\
f_9=x_{12}x_{23}-x_{13}x_{22},\\
f_{10}=x_{12}x_{24}-x_{14}x_{22},\\
f_{11}=x_{13}x_{24}-x_{14}x_{23}
$$

The first syzygy module of $I$ is the kernel of the $R$-module homomorphism $R(-2)^{11} \to I$ with $e_i\to f_i$, where $\{e_i:i\in[11]\}$ is the canonical basis of $R(-2)^{11}$.

How can you compute manually with pen and paper the minimal set of generators of the first syzygy module of $I$?

Using an algebra program as Macaulay2, I find that the generators are given by the combinations of $e_i$ with the following polynomials read by columns

```
     | x_(3,1)  x_(2,1)  0        x_(1,1)  0        0        0       
 {2} | 0        0        0        0        0        0        0       
 {2} | 0        0        0        0        0        x_(2,4)  x_(1,4) 
 {2} | -x_(1,4) 0        x_(1,2)  0        x_(1,1)  0        0       
 {2} | x_(2,4)  0        -x_(2,2) 0        -x_(2,1) 0        0       
 {2} | -x_(3,2) -x_(2,2) 0        -x_(1,2) 0        -x_(2,3) -x_(1,3)
 {2} | 0        x_(2,4)  x_(3,2)  x_(1,4)  x_(3,1)  0        0       
 {2} | 0        0        0        0        0        x_(2,1)  x_(1,1) 
 {2} | 0        0        0        0        0        0        0       
 {2} | 0        0        0        0        0        0        0       
 {2} | 0        0        0        0        0        0        0       
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -x_(2,3) 0        -x_(1,3) 0        0        0        0        0       
 0        0        0        0        0        -x_(3,2) -x_(3,1) 0       
 0        -x_(2,2) 0        x_(3,2)  -x_(1,2) 0        0        0       
 0        0        0        x_(1,3)  0        0        0        -x_(4,2)
 0        0        0        -x_(2,3) 0        x_(4,2)  x_(4,1)  0       
 0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       
 0        x_(2,3)  0        0        x_(1,3)  0        0        0       
 x_(2,2)  0        x_(1,2)  0        0        0        0        0       
 x_(2,4)  x_(2,1)  x_(1,4)  -x_(3,1) x_(1,1)  0        0        0       
 0        0        0        0        0        x_(1,2)  x_(1,1)  -x_(2,2)
 0        0        0        0        0        0        0        x_(3,2) 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -x_(4,1) 0        0        0        0        0                             
 -x_(2,4) 0        -x_(2,3) -x_(2,2) -x_(2,1) 0                             
 0        0        x_(4,2)  0        0        0                             
 0        -x_(4,1) 0        0        0        0                             
 0        0        0        0        0        0                             
 x_(4,2)  0        0        0        0        0                             
 0        0        0        x_(4,2)  x_(4,1)  0                             
 0        0        0        0        0        -x_(3,1)x_(4,2)+x_(3,2)x_(4,1)
 0        0        -x_(4,1) 0        0        0                             
 0        -x_(2,1) 0        0        0        x_(1,3)x_(2,4)-x_(1,4)x_(2,3) 
 x_(1,4)  x_(3,1)  x_(1,3)  x_(1,2)  x_(1,1)  0
```

o6 : Matrix $R^{11}$   <--- $R^{21}$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I edited the question, adding some personal considerations. I don't know if the message is clear, so the main point is to compute the minimal system of generators of the first syzygy of a binomial ideal, using pen and paper and not a software. I hope it's ok now. Warm regards!

Comment: You should probably use Schreyer's Theorem. See Eisenbud's chapter 15 (section 5), or chapters 5 and 6 of Using Algebraic Geometry by Cox, Little, O'Shea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion!